# socketio ip: why is ipfix variable / username not changing

Tags: socket.io

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
var ip = socket.request.connection.remoteAddress;
var ipfix = ip;    // made a copy of ip cause thought it may be a constant
for (var g = 0; g < ipfix.length; g++)
    {
        if (ipfix[g] == 'f' || ipfix[g] == ':')
            {
                ipfix[g] = '';
                console.log("changed to nothing"); // logs to console
            }
        if (ipfix[g] == '.')
            {
                ipfix[g] = '0';
                console.log("changed to zero"); // logs to console
            }
    }
var username = 'User#' + ipfix[9] + ipfix[8] + ipfix[11] + ipfix[13];
console.log(username); // Logs, no change to dots / f / :
}
```

The purpose of this is to remove dots, colons, and 'f' from ip
To me this seems perfectly reasonable, but everytime i've run it, it 
prints out username with no change to the values seen in IP, even 
though IP was copied into ipfix and iterated through.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix, unlike C, javascript strings are immutable - a solution is to use `ipfix = ip.split('');` <-- turns into an array of characters.